# A children's or YA book where the protagonist hasn't had their special power develop; later revealed to be a form of precognition

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, psychic

Okay, this one might be a challenge. I realize that "protagonist is alone in not having magical powers" is a very common trope, but I do remember some other details.

I read this as a child in the 90s, so it'll have been published thenabouts or earlier. The setting was modern; I'm pretty sure there was a reference to someone driving a Land Rover.

I think the protagonist was one of three siblings; both of the other two have had their powers develop. This is supposed to be something that happens at a certain age, possibly puberty. The family live in a rugged, rural setting, maybe in Ireland or Scotland or somesuch?

Eventually it transpires that the protagonist's ability is of a very rare kind, a form of unspecified precognition that can vaguely warn about dangerous events that are about to happen.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art?

Comment: Sorry, no. I read it something like 25 years ago. =/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds very much like *[Power of Three](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6992)*, a novel by Dianne Wynne Jones, first published in 1976.

The story deals with three siblings, Gair, his sister Ayna, and hs younger brother Ceri. They live on the Moor, a fairly rugged rural setting, at a level round about the Middle Ages in technology. They are surrounded by their enemies, the Dorig, who live under water, and the Giants. In fact, while we go through most of the novel from the children's point of view, seeing them and their race as humans, they are in fact members of a separate race of small delicate people called "Lymen". It is the so-called Giants who are we humans, perceived by the Lymen as huge blundering creatures, with a sad ignorance of magic and the power of names.

The three children indeed have gifts. Ayna can predict the future in response to questions, and Ceri has two gifts, a "Finding" gift and the gift of "Thought". Gair initially thinks that he has no gifts, until it finally turns out that he has the gift of "Sight Unasked". That is, he can predict the future, but the precognition arises spontaneously, without needing to be prompted by a question. This gift was extremely uncommon:

> Gair had the rarest Gift of all. Only five people since King Ban the
> Good had had Sight Unasked.

Comment: I wonder if there should be something in here about how the "giants" aren't that gigantic compared to the Lymen. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_Three_(novel) "They look like humans, but are a little smaller, thinner"

Comment: Better now, @Malady ?

Comment: Yep! Thanks! Hope this is the right book, since you put so much work in this answer!

Comment: This is the one! Thanks!